# Android device tokens not always generated in Ionic Apps?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using Ionic Push to create push notifications and it works pretty well.

For some odd reason however, about 20% of the time I cannot see an Android Device Token in the Ionic Apps for a user (note i'm testing on one device).

Is there any reason for this to happen?